# Is it possible to access a UIView's properties (e.g. frame) in init(coder:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nscoder

I am trying to understand how to properly used `NSCoder` when subclassing `UIView`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to access any properties that `aDecoder` might carry. I would e.g. expect it to know the size of the `frame` that the view has in Storyboards. Is it possible to access this information? I tried the following but it only returned 0-values for the `CGRect`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  let frame = aDecoder.decodeCGRect(forKey: "frame")
  print(frame) // prints: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

I checked the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding/1416145-init) of `UIView`, but there is no info on this.

Comment: It will probably change in the first layout pass.  If you are using constraints, the frame won't be in the coder.  Why do you need to know?  What are you trying to accomplish?  There's probably a different way of doing it.

Comment: just tried it after `super.init()` but it still only prints: `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. shouldn't `aDecoder` carry the basic info about the view's setup in storyboards? like `frame` or `backgroundColor` so that it can be used in `UIView`'s initializer?

Comment: 99% of the time the frame of an object in a storyboard will be set by constraints, not a frame specified in the storyboard.  `backgroundColor` is different; this is a property that would typically be set explicitly in the storyboard and should be available after the call to `super.init`.  Normally your subclass will specify, via `intrinsicContentSize` the size that it wants to be

Answer (score -1):

If you need actual dimensions of your custom-view, then you should look at your view's view-controller method:

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Your custom view should have it's proper dimensions set when this gets called.